# Executing GWT application from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I am a beginner in GWT. i came up with my entry class as follows:

```
public class HelloWorld implements EntryPoint {


public void onModuleLoad() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Label label = new Label("Hello GWT !!!");
    Button button = new Button("Say something");
    button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            Window.alert("Hello, again");
        }

    });

    try{
    RootPanel.get("hold").add(label);
    RootPanel.get("hold").add(button);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}

}
```

and the xml file to declare the entry class as:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='testgwt'>
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>
  <!-- Specify the app entry point class -->
  <entry-point class="com.jade.testgwt.client.HelloWorld"/>
</module>
```

the html file is as follows:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="TestGWT.css">
    <title>My First GWT applicaton</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="testgwt/test_gwt.nocache.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>My First GWT applicaton</h1>
    <div id="hold"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

so i was expecting to see the label and button control on the web page when i run by right clicking on the project and choosing Run as Web application. I only got to see the h1's tags text. don't know why the label and button is not showing?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `RootPanel.get("hold").add(...)`, try this:

```
RootLayoutPanel.get().add(label);
RootLayoutPanel.get().add(button);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the fully qualified name of your GWT module? I don't think that `test_gwt.nocache.js` is correct if the module name is `testgwt`. Try removing the underscore. In any case, you could install Firebug in Firefox to monitor the network activity and see if the request to fetch the JS is failing.

Edit: If you create a "New Web Application" project in Eclipse, a working sample application is generated to which you could compare your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take panel. And in that panel add your label and button.

That panel will be added in RootPanel.get("hold").add(...).

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to you HTML page below the division with id **"hold"**

```
<iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex='-1' style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; border: 0"></iframe>
```

You missed out this line.

Also Edit the script tag in the HTML Page as,

Make sure a ***testgwt.nocache.js*** exist under your ***testgwt*** folder